# auto play dot navigation jquery setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to automatically add the active class every 5 seconds to each li tags and
This was the only algorithm that came to my mind.It does not work well.please help me for this problem.

style css in follow

```
       .dots{
            text-align: center;
            background: blue;
        }
        .dots ul{
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
        .dot{
            width:10px;
            height:10px;
            background:white;
            border-radius:50%;
            display:inline-block;
            cursor:pointer;
            margin:0 3px;
        }
        .dots ul .active{
            background:black;
        }
```

html tag in follow

```
<div class="dots">
        <ul>
            <li class="dot active"></li>
            <li class="dot"></li>
            <li class="dot"></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

jquery statement in follow

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            setInterval(function(){
                var n = 1;
                $('.dots ul li:nth-child(n)').removeClass('active');
                $('.dots ul li:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
            }, 5000);
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable n must be defined outside of the setInterval loop. Increment n (e.g. ++n) at every cycle. This is text string - $('.dots ul li:nth-child(n)'). Move number n away from text, for example

```
$('.dots ul li:nth-child(' + n + ')')
```

or

```
$('.dots ul li').eq(n)
```

Modified function will looks like:

```
   $(function(){
        var n = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            $('.dots ul li').eq(n).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            if (++n >= $('.dots ul li').length) n = 0;
        }, 5000);
    });
```